# Unclear error shown by javascript-obfuscator

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to obfuscate a Node.js project using javascript-obfuscator and it goes well for several files, but always fails in a specific one. The file in question have the following code:

**estacao-meteorologica.js:**

```
'use strict';
class EstacaoMeteorologica {

    constructor(urlDadosEstacao, urlDadosMeteorologicos, fazenda) {
        console.log('Do nothing');
    }
}
module.exports = EstacaoMeteorologica;
```

Command used:

```
node_modules/.bin/javascript-obfuscator ./ --exclude node_modules --output ./dist
```

Result:

```
/* A lot of files before... */
[javascript-obfuscator-cli] Obfuscating file: servers\server-estacao-meteorologica\models\index.js...

[javascript-obfuscator-cli] Obfuscating file: servers\server-estacao-meteorologica\models\observacoes.js...

[javascript-obfuscator-cli] Obfuscating file: servers\server-estacao-meteorologica\models\SequelizeMeta.js...

[javascript-obfuscator-cli] Obfuscating file: servers\server-estacao-meteorologica\services\estacao-meteorologica.js...

C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\EspreeFacade.ts:100
        throw new Error(`Line ${position.line}: ${errorMessage}\n${formattedPointer} ${formattedCodeSlice}`);
              ^
Error: Line 50: 'return' outside of function
> ...return;...
    at Function.value (C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\EspreeFacade.ts:100:15)
    at Function.processParsingError (C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\EspreeFacade.ts
:44:46)
    at e.parse (C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\JavaScriptObfuscator.ts:154:29)
    at e.parseCode (C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\JavaScriptObfuscator.ts:135:46)
    at Function.obfuscate (C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\JavaScriptObfuscatorFacad
e.ts:31:70)
    at Function.obfuscate (C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\cli\JavaScriptObfuscatorC
LI.ts:109:61)
    at e.processSourceCodeWithoutSourceMap (C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\cli\Java
ScriptObfuscatorCLI.ts:410:37)
    at e.apply (C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\decorators\Initializable.ts:105:39)
    at processSourceCode (C:\Users\helio.filho\Documents\Repos\bit_repos\jerry-mouse\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\cli\JavaScriptObfuscatorCL
I.ts:379:22)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with the javascript-obfuscator itself. Using **./** to obfuscate all files recursively was causing the problem. The solution was to execute several times for each directory. Example:

```
node_modules/.bin/javascript-obfuscator ./foo/foo2 --exclude node_modules --output ./dist 

node_modules/.bin/javascript-obfuscator ./bar --exclude node_modules --output ./dist

node_modules/.bin/javascript-obfuscator ./dir3 --exclude node_modules --output ./dist
```